# Using Journey Builder Send SMS Activity with Mobile Connect templates

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobileconnect

When creating a MobileConnect message, you can choose from different template options, including:

1. Outbound
2. Text Response
3. Mobile opt-in
4. Info Capture
5. Email Opt-in
6. Survey (if enabled for the account)

This is indicated in the screenshot below.

[image: MobileConnect Templates]

I understand that in order to use the Send SMS Activity in Journey Builder, MobileConnect messages need to be created using the 'Interaction' Send Method. However this method only appears to be available for Outbound templates.

Does this mean that the Journey Builder Send SMS Activity can only send outbound SMS messages? I would like to send an 'Info Capture' message using the Send SMS Activity in Journey Builder to enable recipients to reply to the SMS, then store the response attribute for the Contact. Is this not possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is as per design - only outbound templates are supported. Refer the official [documentation](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/mobileconnect/configuring_mobileconnect_for_use_with_journey_builder/) where it states

> **How to Configure MobileConnect for Use with Journey Builder**
>
> Follow the
> steps below to properly configure your MobileConnect messages for use
> with Journey Builder:
>
> Contact your Salesforce Marketing Cloud relationship manager to ensure
> your account allows access to both MobileConnect (using the upgraded
> version of Contacts) and Journey Builder.
>
> Ensure the MobileConnect
> Demographic data extension contains the contact data used to
> personalize any messages used as part of Journey Builder.
>
> Ensure that
> all contacts you wish to participate in your Journey Builder
> activities subscribe to the appropriate short or long code and
> keyword.
>
> You can specify those subscriptions at import or by using
> messages such as the Mobile Opt-In template.
>
> ***Create all Outbound MobileConnect messages using the Interaction send method to permit Journey Builder access.***
>
> Note that all contacts must initially
> subscribe to your short or long code and keyword to receive messages
> at the beginning of the journey. The contacts must also remain
> subscribed continuously to your short or long code and keyword to
> continue receving messages as part of the Journey Builder activity. If
> the contact unsubscribes at any time, that contact will not receive
> additional messages.
>
> Once you properly configure your MobileConnect messages, those
> messsages become available for addition to Journey Builder
> automatically:
>
> Use the Send SMS activity within Journey Builder. Click Configure to
> select the message you wish to send within that activity. Journey
> Builder will display a list of all messages using the Interaction send
> method.

Answer (score 2):

I've arrived at the conclusion that a Send SMS Activity in Journey Builder can only be used with MobileConnect Outbound message templates.